# getting last records from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have a table which store structure like this

```
id name group_id
1 ABC   1
2 DEF   1
3 GHi   1
4 jkl   2
5 mno   2
6 pqr   2
7 stu   3
8 vwx   3
9 yz0   3
```

I wants to get records by there last group_id's, in above example as 3 is not always same so first I have to get last group id with another query:

```
Selct * FROM records ORDER BY group_ID DESC LIMIT 1;
// so here it gets last group-id which is 3
```

so again I have to perform another query to get those records with last id's

```
// $id = 3 // from above records
Select * From records where group_id = $id
```

is there any better way doing it with single mysql query? i am using codeigniter active records.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, yes its always biggest

Comment: I can't think of anything right now, but it's just better if in the first query you do SELECT id FROM ....,  it's faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE group_ID  = (SELECT MAX(group_ID ) 
                   FROM records);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b4c4/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID | NAME | GROUP_ID |
------------------------
|  7 |  stu |        3 |
|  8 |  vwx |        3 |
|  9 |  yz0 |        3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT x.*
   FROM my_table x
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT MAX(group_id) max_group_id FROM my_table ) y
     ON y.max_group_id = x.group_id;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but I was kind of assuming the same thing here... A join would accomplish those two queries in one.

Comment: Thank you but Mahmoud query looks more simple :)